# Angular 2 - bypassSecurityTrustHtml along with bypassSecurityTrustScript

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, angular2-template, angular2-directives

I have a button (on left navigation side), click on which, I want to display a template (.html) on right side (content section). Template (.html) path will be fetched from web service and would be different every time (so no hard coded values).

That template (.html) can have it's own script tags. Till Angular 1.x it was easy with ng-include tag, but it seems Angular 2 does not support it anymore.

I am able to display HTML's content (as well as CSS) using below workaround -

```
this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(url);
```

But Scripts are not getting loaded or executed.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option of [innerHTML] could work for you when you have single script tag in your HTML content. But if you have multiple Script tags to load with HTML content than it's not a feasible option as it does not guarantee the sequence in which scripts will be loaded and executed. For that you will have to append your HTML in any element and load scripts in a sequence, one by one.

Below solution is properly explained here -
https://ghinda.net/article/script-tags/

Your HTML should look like -

```
<div id="scripts"></div>
<div id="content"></div>
```

In first div, all your Scripts will get appended and in second, all your HTML content will be appended.

First convert your HTML into string and push all script tags into scriptArr[].

```
// run the scripts inside the dom node

    if (scriptArr.length > 0) {
        var $container = document.getElementById('scripts')
        $container.innerHTML = scriptArr
        runScripts($container)
    }

/* helpers */

// runs an array of async functions in sequential order
function seq(arr, callback, index) {
    // first call, without an index
    if (typeof index === 'undefined') {
        index = 0
    }

    arr[index](function () {
        index++
        if (index === arr.length) {
            callback()
        } else {
            seq(arr, callback, index)
        }
    })
}

// trigger DOMContentLoaded
function scriptsDone() {
    var DOMContentLoadedEvent = document.createEvent('Event')
    DOMContentLoadedEvent.initEvent('DOMContentLoaded', true, true)
    document.dispatchEvent(DOMContentLoadedEvent)
}

/* script runner */

function insertScript($script, callback) {
    var s = document.createElement('script')
    if (!s.type) {
        s.type = 'text/javascript'
    }
    if ($script.src) {
        s.onload = callback
        s.onerror = callback
        s.src = $script.src
    } else {
        s.textContent = $script.innerText
    }

    // re-insert the script tag so it executes.
    document.head.appendChild(s)

    // clean-up
    $script.parentNode.removeChild($script)

    // run the callback immediately for inline scripts
    if (!$script.src) {
        callback()
    }
}

// https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html
var runScriptTypes = [
            'application/javascript',
            'application/ecmascript',
            'application/x-ecmascript',
            'application/x-javascript',
            'text/ecmascript',
            'text/javascript',
            'text/javascript1.0',
            'text/javascript1.1',
            'text/javascript1.2',
            'text/javascript1.3',
            'text/javascript1.4',
            'text/javascript1.5',
            'text/jscript',
            'text/livescript',
            'text/x-ecmascript',
            'text/x-javascript'
        ]

function runScripts($container) {
    // get scripts tags from a node
    var $scripts = $container.querySelectorAll('script')
    var runList = []
    var typeAttr

    [].forEach.call($scripts, function ($script) {
        typeAttr = $script.getAttribute('type')

        // only run script tags without the type attribute
        // or with a javascript mime attribute value
        if (!typeAttr || (runScriptTypes ? runScriptTypes.indexOf(typeAttr) !== -1 : 'text/javascript')) {
            runList.push(function (callback) {
                insertScript($script, callback)
            })
        }
    })

    // insert the script tags sequentially
    // to preserve execution order
    seq(runList, scriptsDone)
}

let fragment = document.createRange()
    .createContextualFragment(html);

// fragment.baseURI = 'http://toolsqaplp/publish/Dev_Testing/n1d/DS_MAC/en/CATMMGSkillets_en.edu/CATMMGEdc0020_en.doc/src/';
document.getElementById('content')
    .appendChild(fragment);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The [official document](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer) says that `bypassSecurityTrustHtml()` should work in your case.

I am also assuming you must be using `[innerHTML]` attribute to populate contents in target container.

I had kind of similar reuirement where I needed single HTML tag with single script tag. I used `bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl()` for that.

```
return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(url)
```

I am pretty sure it will work in your case too as you are fetching executable source.

You can also try combimation `bypassSecurityTrustScript()` and `bypassSecurityTrustHtml()`.